# How do you test the each element inside String Array in java Junit5?

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd, junit4

Let's say I have this following String Array

```
String[] expected = new String[]{"rock", "paper", "scissor"};
```

Sounds dummy, I am fairly new junit5, how do you do test element inside the String Array? I only know how to compare two different String Array by doing this.

```
@Test
    public void testStringArray() throws Exception {
        String[] expected = new String[]{"rock", "paper", "scissor"};
        String[] actual = new String[]{"rock", "paper", "sci"};
        assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);

    }
```

Now I want to test each element from the 'expected' individually, is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What do you mean by, _"test each element individually"_?

Comment: I mean let's say you add 3 strings to String Array,  I want to test if those are the same inside the String Array you created.  My apologies if it confuses you

Comment: Isn't that what the _assertArrayEquals_ method does?  Possibly, you are looking to locate just one value?  You can use _List.of(actual).contains("value")_.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `assertArrayEquals()` method for array comparing, If you use pure JUnit API. check this [Junit document](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assert.html#:%7E:text=assertArrayEquals,-public%20static%20void&text=junit.internal.ArrayComparisonFailure-,Asserts%20that%20two%20object%20arrays%20are%20equal.,null%20%2C%20they%20are%20considered%20equal.)

If you use `assertj` as assertion library, you can use `usingRecursiveComparison()` method when you start builder.

PS. this question can be searchable easily... please google it as possible as you can and create question if there is no answer.